# How to remove special characters from URL permalinks

Tags: special-characters, jekyll, permalinks

I am starting with jekyll and i'll appreciate any kind of help.

I am making a blog site but not in english language.

Default language will be Czech so in post tittles there will be characters like ĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍ.

I want to use pretty permalinks with post tittle in it, but actualy it doesn't work

properly in Safari browser. I am getting error 500 from server.

How to resolve it? Is there any plugin which can convert these characters in ascii symbols escrzyai and how to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe permalinks are determined by settings + post file names, not settings + post titles.

So you should have files names like

```
_posts\2014-04-12-hello-world.md
```

instead of

```
_posts\2014-04-12-je-každoročně-tak-veliký.md
```

Inside the post, you can still use post title in Czech.

Permalinks' documentation is [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/), note if you have Czech categories and you use them in permalinks, you will still get into trouble, so it's better to avoid Czech categories in permalinks.